# bash: Split binary file at predefined positions

Tags: bash, split, binary

I have binary files which contain data structures **of various length**. I would like to save these blocks of data into separate files. The size of each block is known. The `split` command can, well, split a file but it does not stop after the first block of data. It slices the file into pieces of equal size.

Therefore, my current solution is to `split` and `cat` the remainder of the file back together, iterating my way through the data. This is very clumsy and may even fail in certain circumstances.

What is the best way to slice a binary file precisely at certain positions?

Comment: It would be a bit more manual but you could use `dd`.

Comment: If I see it correctly, `dd` lets me copy the first block of arbitrary size, but then I can skip only at multiples within the input and output files, respectively. I would need offset and block size as independant parameters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use two independent `dd` commands. One to seek arbitrarily, and another to copy arbitrary lengths.

```
SEEK=501
BYTES=387
dd if=yourfile bs=$SEEK skip=1 | dd bs=$BYTES count=1 > lump.bin
```

**Note**: Although counter-intuitive to what you are actually try to do, keep the blocksize high and the count low for best performance. What I mean is, if you want 8192 bytes, use `bs=8192 count=1` rather than `bs=1 count=8192`.

Comment: Thank you. It solves my problem. And it is not counter-intuitive at all.

Comment: Excellent! Saved a hell of a lot of time in my case

Answer (score 1):

> I would need offset and block size as independant parameters.

Using the `iflag` operand may help you here. It is available in **dd (coreutils)** since 2012, and you can specify different units for `bs`, `skip` and `count`.

Note that `skip` and `count` must either be in bytes or match the `bs` value.

An example usage will be:

```bash
dd if=infile.bin of=outfile.bin bs=4K skip=1234 count=20 iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes
```

which would copy 20 bytes from input file, starting from byte 1235.

You can refer here for more detailed usage: https://askubuntu.com/a/1178771